# Parse Command line arguments within a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, command-line-arguments

This is my requirement -

I have to get the inputs from Command line in the form

```
-des <destIP> -prot <tcp/udp> -min <minutes>
```

There are several programs that suggest how to parse these values through the argc and argv parameters of main() function. But I want a function which gets the iput line and then parse it.

The function would be -

```
void GetArguments()
{
    cout << "Enter arguments ..." << endl;
    cin >> inputStr;//eg: inputStr = "-des 127.0.0.1 -prot tcp -min 60"

    //code to parse the input arguments and get values of dest IP, protocol and time
}
```

How do I get the values I need?

Comment: You'll need to pass the arguments of the `main()` function to this function (`GetArguments()`). There's no other way to get the _input line_.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) to parse a `wchar_t*`, such as from a `std::wstring`, into a `wchar_t*[]` array that you can loop through, just like with `argv`/`argc`.  For example:

```
void GetArguments()
{
    std::wstring inputStr;
    std::wcout << L"Enter arguments ..." << std::endl;
    std::wcin >> inputStr;

    int numArgs;
    LPWSTR *args = CommandLineToArgvW(inputStr.c_str(), &numArgs);
    if (args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numArgs; ++i)
        {
            // use args[i] as needed...
        }
        LocalFree(args);
    }
}
```

This is a Windows-specific solution, since your question is tagged for Visual Studio.  If you are looking for a pure C++ solution, you will have to tokenize `inputStr` manually, splitting it on whitespace and quotations as needed. There are tons of examples of that floating around.

Comment: What is the header that I need to include for LPWSTR and CommandLineToArgvW()?

Comment: If you read the documentation I linked you to, it tells you that `CommandLineToArgvW()` is declared in `Shellapi.h`.  As for `LPWSTR`, it is declared in `WinNT.h`, which is included by `Windows.h`.